# how to shows latest Post on Top from User

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, jquery, gridview

I have 3-4 forms where user enter travel information, one form is for flight, road, bus etc,
information is saving into respective tables in database(So all the field are different).

How can i show latest post on top on single Page? i.e if user enter flight information and then enters Bus information, New Post keeps coming on top of same page..
My Database is Sql Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Col1, Col2, Col3, .......  --<----- All the columns you want to show
FROM Table1
WHERE Condition1 ...
ORDER BY Date_Entry_Column DESC
```

**Edit**
I think your question is that you have data in multiple tables and you want to show the last entry made for each client. you could do something like this....

```
SELECT a.x, b.y , c.z
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Col1 AS x 
      FROM TableName1 
      WHERE Some_Condition 
      ORDER BY Date_Entry DESC) a, 
      (SELECT TOP 1 Col2 AS x 
      FROM TableName2 
      WHERE Some_Condition 
      ORDER BY Date_Entry DESC) b,
      (SELECT TOP 1 Col3 AS z 
      FROM TableName3 
      WHERE Some_Condition 
      ORDER BY Date_Entry DESC) c
```

`Selecting TOP 1` will return only one record/row back and if you are looking for the last data input by the client then you would `ORDER BY` the results Descending by the date insert column, In above Query you can get Last records inserted by each client using ClientID in your where condition. Then outer select query will return One row combining result sets returned by multiple Select queries from different tables.

Comment: thanks for that.. this will fetch the top 1 rows, but what about the page where all the information has to be merged to show as one (lets say Gridview) i can not use gridview for each datatable coming from databse,

Comment: Not sure if i understood you but removing Top 1 would retrieve all the rows. Setting your Where condition can limit the results i.e. user's Id in the Where condition would limit it to that user